# CSS style not applied for a page in two different server environments specific to IE browser

Tags: html, css, iis-7, cross-browser

I have created a simple web app. When I deployed the application to Dev and QA servers everything works absolutely fine. When I deploy the same code base to Staging servers, I find many CSS styles not applied properly. several Div tags dislocated and scattered at other places. More interestingly this is only happening with IE browsers. (I am using IE9). Application has been hosted in IIS servers. Does anyone face similar issue like this? Let me know if I need to provide some more details?

One more observation after I did a comparison using Dev tools. Staging server doesn't have some missing attributes in the CSS class. How come this possible?

Comment: Did you verify the CSS file was fully uploaded to staging? Compare file sizes and checksums?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking if your divs that aren't displaying properly have the same rule applied to them multiple times. One rule will be over-riding the other.

Open an inspector, and look for duplicated rules. In general, the rules will be applied in the order that they are loaded, which may not match in your different environments.

Comment: Hi Kim.. Thanks for your reply. I did some additional research and identified that the staging application has IE7 document compatibility mode while Dev and QA has IE9 document compatibility. When I change the compatibility to IE9 in Dev tools Site looks as good as in Dev. My next questions was why this compatibility issue happend?

Comment: I resolve the issue. There was a setting in IIS that allows on IE7 compatibility. I have removed the setting and the site works fine. This link helped me to resolve the issue.
http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/03/23/force-ie7-compatibility-mode-in-ie8-with-iis-settings.aspx

Thank you Kim for your time on this. Appreciate it.